# Python: How to replace beginning and ending brackets without using .replace([ or ])

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My output is supposed to be incased in brackets like so:

```
[[ken alex boz you]
[ken alex you boz]
[ken you boz alex]
[alex you ken boz]
]
```

I need to delete the very first [ as well as the very last ].
Is there a way without replacing all of the brackets?

Comment: what is your output? string?

Comment: Delete from where? What is this thing? A list of lists?

Comment: what does this have to do with tkinter? You've shown no tkinter code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a string slice to remove the first and last character

```
test = '[[ken alex box you] [ken alex you boz]]'
print(test[1:-1:])
>> [ken alex box you] [ken alex you boz]
```

or if you want to get really cryptic you can replace the first occurrence of `'['` on both sides of the string

```
test = '[[ken alex box you] [ken alex you boz]]'
print(test.replace('[', '', 1)[::-1].replace(']', '', 1)[::-1])
>> [ken alex box you] [ken alex you boz]
```

Comment: Great guy. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you want the things between the two outermost brackets,

```
def get_bracket_contents(s):
    left = s.index('[')
    right = s.rindex(']')
    return s[left+1:right]
```

If you want to only remove the brackets,

```
def remove_outer_brackets(s):
    left = s.index('[')
    right = s.rindex(']', left)
    return s[:left] + s[left+1:right] + s[right+1:]
```

The differences:

```
In [3]: get_bracket_contents(' [[abc][def]] ')
Out[3]: '[abc][def]'
In [4]: remove_outer_brackets(' [[abc][def]] ')
Out[4]: ' [abc][def] '
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the first and last characters of the string.Simply use slice to remove them.
   Here is the code I have written:

```
 str = "[[ken alex boz you] [ken alex you boz] [ken you boz alex] [alex you ken boz]]"
 req_str = str[1:len(str)-1]
 print(req_str)
```

Comment: You don't need to reference `len(str)` in the middle value of your slice

Answer (score -3):

If you are certain they will always be at the leading and trailing edges of your string, use [`lstrip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip) and `rstrip` like this:

`s.lstrip('[').rstrip(']')`

Comment: This will remove multiple brackets